How did people keep salt in Eastern Europe's rural communities in the 1940s?
In a collection of testimonies (Alexievitch's Last Witnesses, I believe), I have read about balls of salt in accounts of life in rural communities in the forties in Eastern Europe, but trying to picture it many questions arise (and I haven't managed to find any image).
If these balls are for real, what size would they have been? What color (white, gray,...), what texture (rock hard or crumbly)? Also, where would they have been stored? Would anyone have had them at home, or just store owners?

Where did you read about it? Was it an academic text about Eastern Europe or a general text about the war...or something else?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineral_lick ?

Thursday salt is a mix of salt and flavourings prepared in Russia during the Holy Week, baked into a black lump. According to the russian WP article, it is not kept in that form, but immediately crushed again in a mortar.

Vague questions result in speculative answers.
So, let's assume the book you do only believe to remember is "Last Witnesses: An Oral History of the Children of World War II" by Svetlana Alexievich. Some years back, Alexievich published some excerpts from this book on her own website. They were since deleted, but the Internet Archive still has the file.
Now we need to speculate that the following quote (p. 13/14) is actually what you remember from the book.

…Меня закутывают во что-то и мы прячемся в болоте. Весь день и всю ночь. Ночь холодная. Кричат страшным голосом незнакомые птицы. Кажется, что луна светит ярко-ярко. Страх! А если нас увидят или услышат немецкие овчарки? Иногда долетал их хриплый лай. Наутро – домой! Я хочу домой! Все хотят домой, в тепло! Но дома уже нет, только груда дымящихся головешек. Обгоревшее место… После большого костра… Находим в золе ком соли, который всегда у нас лежал на припечке. Аккуратно собрали соль, потом и глину, смешанную с солью, ссыпали ее в кувшин. Это все, что осталось от нашего дома…

DeepL.com translates this to English as:

...They wrap me in something and we hide in the swamp. All day and all night. The night is cold. There are strange birds screaming in a frightening voice. The moon seems to shine brightly. Fear! What if the German shepherd dogs see or hear us? Sometimes their hoarse barking could be heard. In the morning - home! I want to go home! Everyone wants to go home, to warmth! But the house is gone, just a pile of smoking heads. A burnt place... After a big fire... We found a lump of salt in the ash, which was always lying on the stove. We carefully collected the salt, then the clay mixed with salt and poured it into a jug. That's all that was left of our house.....

In that case, you might have misinterpreted what you read. Salt stood on top of a stove, presumably in some container. When the house burned down, the salt baked into a lump and partially mixed with clay (from the container?).
The "ком соли", the "lump of salt" was a result of the catastrophy, not something that was prepared deliberately.
But maybe that is a mistranslation. The belarussian word "припечке" does not show up in online dictionaries, and while "печка" is a stove, is that really the same?
